# С'ишная строка, ошибка

Tags: c++, строки

```
int main() {
     char* s = "sa sadlas,ldlas, ,dlas,ld as ";
}
```

Как исправить ошибку, не используя const и string?

Comment: А подумать? :) `char s?? = "sa sadlas,ldlas, ,dlas,ld as ";` — что-то надо поставить вместо `??`. Ну, что? :)

Comment: Например, `char *s = (__typeof__(s))"....";`

Comment: `auto & s{"sa sadlas,ldlas, ,dlas,ld as "};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
const char* s = (char*) "sa sadlas,ldlas, ,dlas,ld as ";
```

Вариант 2:

```
char s[] = "sa sadlas,ldlas, ,dlas,ld as ";
```

Вариант 3:

```
std::string s = "sa sadlas,ldlas, ,dlas,ld as ";
```

Comment: Вариант 1 у вас содержит грубую ошибку. А именно, указателю на *неконстантную* строку присваивается адрес строки, размещаемой компилятором в *константной* секции программы, которая защищена от записи! Таким образом, любая попытка модификации этой строки через указатель `s` приведёт к падению программы.